# Significant performance issue with Django Admin - foreign key labels

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I’m experience significant performance issue with Django Admin.

I have a mapping model where I map primary keys of 2 other modes

In my FundManagerMappingAdmin I try to represent the foreign key of the 2 tables with a label from the foreign key models.

The underlying models are about 4000 lines

I’m experiencing slow performance when retrieving the list in admin and then also when editing and updating

Could someone please point out the inefficiencies in this code?

Is there a better way please?

**Admin.py**

```
@admin.register(ChampDwDimFundManagerMapping)
class FundManagerMappingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

list_display = ['get_champ_fund_manager_id', 'get_evestment_name', 'get_sharepoint_name', ]

def get_champ_fund_manager_id(self, obj):
    return obj.fund_manager_id
get_champ_fund_manager_id.short_description = 'CHAMP Manager ID'

def get_evestment_name(self, obj):
    return obj.evestment_fund_manager_id.manager_name
get_evestment_name.short_description = 'Evestment Manager Name'

def get_sharepoint_name(self, obj):
    return obj.sharepoint_fund_manager_id.manager_name
get_sharepoint_name.short_description = 'Sharepoint Manager Name'

def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super(ChampFundManagerMappingAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    form.base_fields['sharepoint_fund_manager_id'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: "{} {}".format(obj.final_publications_fund_manager_id, obj.manager_name)
    form.base_fields['evestment_fund_manager_id'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: "{} {}".format(obj.evestment_fundmanager_id_bk, obj.manager_name)
    return form
```

**Models.py**

```
class FundManagerMapping(models.Model):
    fund_manager_id = models.AutoField(db_column='FundManagerId', primary_key=True)  
    sharepoint_fund_manager_id = models.ForeignKey(SharePointFundManager, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='SharePointFundManagerId')  
    evestment_fund_manager_id = models.ForeignKey(EvestmentFundManager, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='eVestmentFundManagerId')  

class EvestmentFundManager(models.Model):
    evestment_fund_manager_id = models.AutoField(db_column='eVestmentFundManagerId', primary_key=True)  
    package_execution_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='PackageExecutionId')  
    evestment_fund_manager_id_bk = models.CharField(db_column='eVestmentFundManagerId_BK', max_length=50)  
    manager_name = models.CharField(db_column='ManagerName', max_length=255)  

class SharePointFundManager(models.Model):
    sharepoint_fund_manager_id = models.AutoField(db_column='SharePointFundManagerId', primary_key=True)  
    package_execution_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='PackageExecutionId')  
    research_fund_manager_id = models.CharField(db_column='ResearchFundManagerId', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  
    final_publications_fund_manager_id = models.CharField(db_column='FinalPublicationsFundManagerId', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  
    manager_name = models.CharField(db_column='ManagerName', max_length=255)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are showing the `name` of related entities (because of `get_evestment_name` and `get_sharepoint_name`) without joining/prefetching them. That means for every row that you display and every name of the related entity it requires django to make a database query. You need to override `get_queryset()` of the `ModelAdmin` and use `select_related` to tell django to join those entities from the beginning so that it does not need any additional queries to get those names:

```
@admin.register(ChampDwDimFundManagerMapping)
class FundManagerMappingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super().get_queryset(request).select_related(
            'sharepoint_fund_manager_id', 
            'evestment_fund_manager_id',
        )
```

Also you don't name `ForeignKey` fields `something_id`. It is just `sharepoint_fund_manager` because what you get when you call `fund_manager.sharepoint_fund_manager_id` is not an id but an instance of `SharePointFundManager`. It is weird to call `sharepoint_fund_manager_id.name`. An id does not have a name attribute. A fund manager has.

Additionally Django does automatically create a property `sharepoint_fund_manager_id` for you if you call the field `sharepoint_fund_manager` to access the plain foreign key.

Comment: Thanks rolled out the recommended changes and the design flaws and works well, a performance improvement noticed

Comment: @RachOdwyer Glad it helped. If you want to debug whether a certain view produces duplicated or similar queries you can install the [Django Debug Toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It is a small tool that helps you inspect different metrics in your browser, among that it shows you every query being made and highlights duplicates.